# How do I change the background image of a chart in vba?

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I need to change the background image of a chart I created using vba. I tried using the .Fill command but I can't make it work. How do I do it?
This is the code I used to create the chart and it is working fine:

```
With myChart
    .ChartStyle = 245
    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .SeriesCollection(1).Name = ""
    .HasLegend = False
    .Axes(xlCategory).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlCategory).AxisTitle.Text = "Punteggio Tecnico"
    .Axes(xlValue).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlValue).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Punteggio Economico"
    .Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = 0
    .Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = 1
    .Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = 0
    .Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 1
    .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Dati2!B3:B270"
    .SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=Dati2!C3:C270"
End With
```

Comment: Can you share exactly how you are using `.Fill` and how it's not working?

Comment: @J.schmidt The `Excel-VBA` tag is pending removal so shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `myChart` is `Chart` variable then you want the `myChart.PlotArea.Format.Fill` for the area of the chart that contains the actual chart, or `myChart.ChartArea.Format.Fill` for the whole chart area.

The code below shows how to use it.  I've commented out the colouring code that a macro recorder would supply and replaced with a basic RGB value.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim myChart As Chart

    Set myChart = Sheet1.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Chart

    With myChart
        With .PlotArea.Format.Fill
            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)

'            .Visible = msoTrue
'            .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent6
'            .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
'            .ForeColor.Brightness = 0.400000006
'            .Solid
        End With

        With .ChartArea.Format.Fill
            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)

'            .Visible = msoTrue
'            .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent6
'            .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
'            .ForeColor.Brightness = 0.400000006
'            .Transparency = 0
'            .Solid
        End With

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Good stuff.  Feel free to tick as accepted answer. :)